# how to upgrade ubuntu 10.04 LTS to ubuntu 13.04 without internet?

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, 10.04, offline

No internet,NO cd/dvd rom, only USB.
I have no idea how to upgrade the system.
Any one can tell?

Comment: you can boot from usb, there you should have option to upgrade the system, directly from usb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I THINK the only way to do it would be to get someone with Internet to [follow these instructions for 13.04](http://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and then you will have to put it into your PC, reboot to the bootloader (you might need to press ESC or F5 or something while booting to get to the Startup Menu in your PC) and then select USB. You can then select the option 'Upgrade to 13.04' to keep your files.

You might want to back-up your data maybe by simply copying the files in your Home Folder to an external hard-drive and then copying them back if you need to.

Comment: Thanks and is that mean re-install the system?As I know,I should choose "intallation type" when I intall .1."install ubuntu 13.04 alongside existed system" ,2."upgrade ubuntu 13.04" 3.re-install ubuntu. option 2 is keep data, option 3 is delete all data?

Comment: Yeah if you click 'Upgrade to 13.04' I ASSUME that upgrades it, whereas 're-install Ubuntu' would wipe it, but I don't actually know... I recommend purchasing a USB external hard drive and backing up first and regularly backing up with 'Backup' in the future, but you don't HAVE to, it's just there is a chance you could lose all your data if you don't. Same applies to any other operating system by the way...

Comment: @KennethH, not really, check instalation options, you should have an option - upgrade only

Comment: @KennethH You also can [make a mirror](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352460) then upgrade your system from it. Just select the right architecture and release before actions.

Comment: Well the first problem with that is that the Terminal command he gives only works with the Internet, so you would need to get the .debs for each package off another PC.

Comment: @Ads20000, there are two ways I know: update only needed packages using Synaptic and use a mirror as I suggested.

Comment: @Ads20000 I see,I will back up,I dont want to lose data,thank you for your advice.